# How to limit Text Field with autocomplete to items in the list - Oracle Apex 5

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle Apex 5.  I have a text field with autocomplete. I want to limit input to items in the list. My research show that earlier versions of Apex had a setting to do exactly this: 'Only values from list'. Can't seem to find the equivalent setting in Apex 5.

Comment: I can't find that option neither but for things like this i love the [Apex Select2 Plugin](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=64237:20::::::). Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You have the "Display Extra values" Yes/No for this in the section for "List of values"
Kjell